# Is there a way to find duplicate values in a for loop without returning 2 times the duplicated value?

Tags: xquery

I must find duplicates values without returning 2 times the same value in error (fist time the "for" loop on the value and the second time the "for" loops on the same value further in the collection).

I run through a collection of items which have a "name" attribute that should be unique.
For now I have a simple for loop that give me some errors when duplicates are detected.
The problem is that I know there is a way to parse the collection without taking into account the current index of the value to be tested.

So if I have item A, B, C, D and E, with attribute name equal to (in order) : 12, 13, 14, 12 and 16 the current loop will return an error 2 times.
First time because it detects item A has the same value that item D and second time when it detects item D has the same value as A.

```
<errors>
{
    let $LPsList := //TrainingContextCommsCol/theContextsComms/theComms/theOldiComms/ref-LPsList
    for $LP in $LPsList
        let $LPDup := $LPsList[name = $LP/name]
        return
            if (count($LPDup) > 1) then
                <error id="{$rule_id}">
                    <args>
                        <arg value="{$LP/name}"/>
                    </args>
                    <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($LP)}"/>
                </error>
            else ()
}
</errors>
```

I know there is a way to check the duplicate if you count values in the sequence starting at index i + 1 to eliminate the current position, but I don't see how to do that.
So that each time the FOR is going further you "forget" the previous position already checked.

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't got XQuery 3.1 then you could simply change your condition `count($LPDup) > 1` to `count($LPDup) > 1 and $LP is $LPDup[1]` - but the XQuery 3.1 solution is much nicer.

Comment: As I work with 1.0 I will take this as a solution. I guess my brain is a bit foggy to not have seen that easy way before... :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming XQuery 3 or 3.1:

```
<errors>
{
    let $LPsList := //TrainingContextCommsCol/theContextsComms/theComms/theOldiComms/ref-LPsList
    for $LP in $LPsList
    group by $name := $LP/name
    where tail($LP)
    return
          <error id="{$rule_id}">
                    <args>
                        <arg value="{$name}"/>
                    </args>
                    <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($LP[1])}"/>
          </error>
}
</errors>
```

I think `tail` might be not available in XQuery 3.0 but you can of course use `where $LP[2]` instead.